# Combo Box Column Count culls data?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Basically, I have a combo box that I'm using to select a record. That combo box then populates several textbox's that are found on my form based on the ID. See the two images:

[image: here]

[image: here].

I'd like the combo box to show the first two columns in my query, which consists of 16 fields. The Abbreviation and the Name, to be exact. However, I found that if I hid the fields in the query or if I limited the column count of the combo box so it only displays the two, it actually culled the data so that the textbox's would not find it (thus be blank).

My question is, how can I just show the first two columns of the combo box yet still use it's ID to reference all sixteen?

---

Query

```
SELECT Tradeshows.tradeShowAppreviation, 
Tradeshows.tradeShowName, Tradeshows.tradeShowID, 
Tradeshows.tradeShowWebsite, Tradeshows.tradeShowLocation, 
Tradeshows.tradeShowDateStart, Tradeshows.tradeShowDateEnd, 
Tradeshows.tradeShowBoothSize, Tradeshows.tradeShowShipDate, 
Tradeshows.tradeShowAudience, Tradeshows.tradeShowFocus,
Tradeshows.tradeShowMailer, Tradeshows.tradeShowDoorDrop, 
Tradeshows.tradeShowProductFocus, Tradeshows.tradeShowAttendees, 
Tradeshows.tradeShowMembers, Tradeshows.tradeShowMemberships
FROM Tradeshows;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not change the column count, change the column widths.

```
Column width: 0cm;2cm;1cm;0cm
```

And so on.

it should not be difficult to only select the relevant columns. You could post the Row Source property of your combo.

It seems to me that you should be binding you table to the data source TradeShows and using the wizard to create a combobox that finds record.

You can do this by selecting the table Tradeshows and choosing either create form or form. You will now have a form with the RecordSource property set to TradeShows. Next, choose to add a combobox to the form, ensuring that you have selected the wizard (the magic wand button is highlighted). You will be given the option to "Find a record on my form based on the value I select in my combobox". You can choose this and step through the wizard. When you get to the step where you choose fields, make sure you choose the TradeShowID first, and then the name and / or abbreviation. If TradeShowID is the primary key, as it should be, the column will be automatically hidden in the next step, which will show the fields selected.
 The result of these actions will be a combobox with the following properties:

```
Row Source    : SELECT [Tradeshows].[tradeShowID], [Tradeshows].[tradeShowName], 
                [Tradeshows].[tradeShowAppreviation] FROM [Tradeshows];
Bound Column  : 1
Column Count  : 3
Column Widths : 0cm;2.54cm;2.54cm
```

You will also have [Embedded Macro] in the After Update event (2010 and possible 2007) or [Event Procedure] for earlier versions. The wizard code is pretty poor, but that is another days work.

If you still wish to do all the work of setting each control to the (possibly changing) column order, you can follow a similar lay out for the combo, setting counts and widths appropriately.

Comment: Ensure your bound column is the ID column in your combo box and do Remou's above. I'm assuming you're performing a query to fill the text boxes after the combo box selection based on the ID placed in the combo box.

Comment: The table above is the row source. For the other textbox's, I've set the control source to "=[cmbAbbr].[Column](x)", where x is the correct column. Setting the width doesn't do much, as a width of 0 is still visible for some reason.

Comment: An image is of very limited use in questions. You need to post the text from row source, or if it is based on a query, post the sql of the query. Why did you not just bind your form to the query and use the combo to find the relevant record?